# pull finding no changes with hgscc

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mercurial, bitbucket

My friend and me have been trying to set up a common repository. We're both able to push without problems; but when I'm trying to pull my friend's changes, hgscc reports "no files changed". This is despite us using exactly the same link to push & pull.

Please could anyone tell what are we doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the changes you made yourself of course need not pulling. Thus it's correct that no changes are being pulled.

Comment: er, I seem to be wrong. I need of course to pull _my friend's changes_